# Javascript div fade in not working using setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval, fadein

I'm trying to make a div containing a number of pictures to fade in but its not working and I don't know why. I believe that the inverval is not even being called. The div's opacity is set to 0.0 This is the code:

```
var movies = getElementById("movies");

    var apparence = function(){
        if(movies.style.opacity < 1.0){
            movies.style.opacity = movies.style.opacity + 0.1;
        } else { clearInterval(timer);
        }

    }

    var timer = window.setInterval(apparence, 1000);
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: @SethMcClaine document.ready is jQUery.

Comment: @Tomas piaggio -  accept the answer if you find it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your movies var, you need to call:

```
document.getElementById('movies');
```

The way you are attempting to increment opacity didn't work, so I've updated your example.

**New Code:**

```
var movies = document.getElementById("movies");
var opacity = 0.1;
var apparence = function(){
    if(opacity <= 1.0) {
        movies.style.opacity =  opacity;
    } else { 
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    opacity += 0.1;
}

var timer = window.setInterval(apparence, 1000);
```

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/onov6cq4/1/

Comment: Thank you very much it was really helpful specially as I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem

Problem1:
If you have defined your css using

```
#movies {
  opacity: 0.0;
}
```

then `document.getElementById().style.opacity` is empty since it takes from inline style i.e. `<div id="movies" style="opacity: 0.0">`

Problem 2:
movies.style.opacity = movies.style.opacity + 0.1;
movies.style.opacity returns a string so you are basically appending string which results in 0.10.1 and so on. You need to do parseFloat! The attached fiddle will solve your problem

Code:

```
var moviesOp = document.getElementById('movies').style.opacity;

    function apparence(){
      console.log('interval called with op = ' + moviesOp);
        if(moviesOp < 1.0){
            moviesOp = parseFloat(moviesOp, 10) + 0.1;
        } else { 
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    var timer = setInterval(apparence, 1000);

<div id="movies" style="opacity: 0.0">
```

[JSBin With Inline Style](http://jsbin.com/qoyeyu/5/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

If you want to use in css and not inline then use getComputedStyle. This i tried and works as u wanted

```
var movies = document.getElementById('movies');

    function apparence(){
      var moviesOp = getComputedStyle(movies).getPropertyValue('opacity');
      console.log('interval called with op = ' + moviesOp);
        if(moviesOp < 1.0){
            movies.style.opacity = parseFloat(moviesOp, 10) + 0.1;
        } else { 
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }

    var timer = setInterval(apparence, 1000);
```

[Non Inline jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qoyeyu/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: You need to set `moviesOp` inside the function. Otherwise it will always be the original opacity, not the updated value. And you need to set the new opacity style.

Comment: Your jsbins aren't working for me. Why don't you use a stack snippet instead of using an external site?

Comment: @Barmar - thanks for the suggestion, its working fine now : ). Barmar i ve not user stack snipper till now,  lemme get back to u in sometime.

Comment: @Barmar you need to add /edit to the link and then it will work.I have also changed the link so it should work perfectly fine for you now!